# What is the difference between getIntent() and new Intent() in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I do like this

first way

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.putExtra("isLoggedIn",true);
setResult(RESULT_OK,intent);
```

second way

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
intent.putExtra("isLoggedIn",true);
setResult(RESULT_OK,intent);
```

Both can give the same result.I want to know the actual difference between this two

Comment: What does the documentation for `getIntent()` tell you?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the context of an `Activity`, `getIntent()` will return the `Intent` that was originally sent to the `Activity`. The example you gave may work the same, but you should really avoid using `getIntent()` if you are passing the `Intent` to another `Activity` or sending it back as a result.

For example:

If I start an activity with:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("key", "test");
startActivity(intent);
```

Then in my MainActivity class:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String value = intent.getString("key"); // value will = "test".
```

So now consider if you have SecondActivity and I am starting it from MainActivity using getInent();

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
intent.setClassName("com.example.pkg", "com.example.pkg.SecondActivity"");
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.example.pkg", "com.example.pkg.SecondActivity"));
intent.putExtra("isLoggedIn",true);
startActivity(intent);
```

Then in my SecondActivity I can access key and isLoggedIn both.

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String value = intent.getString("key"); // value will = "test".
boolean testIsLoggedIn = intent.getBooleanExtra("isLoggedIn",true);
```

So, generally it is not good practice to use the getIntent to start further activities.